# Login Citadel mail server issue on raspberry pi 3 B

Tags: email, server, raspberry-pi3, debian-stretch

I have installed Citadel mail server on my Raspberry Pi 3 running raspbian with apache2 because I am already running a nextcloud server on it.
The installation process completes without any errors.

I am able to get on the citadel's login screen with my browser on port 8080 and I can't seem to get passed the login screen.
Login and password is correct. I know that because I don't get any errors like wrong password or user does not exist, after clicking login I get nothing. Login page just refreshes.

I tried those commands

```
sudo mkdir /etc/citadel/netconfigs

sudo chown citadel:citadel /etc/citadel/netconfigs
and 

sudo service citadel restart

sudo /usr/lib/citadel-server/setup
```

Didn't change anything.

Tried purging and reinstalling the suite, reconfiguring everything and I get to the same point.
I made sure to delete any remaing files or configs before reinstalling so I am out of ideas.

If you need any more information or have me to check error logs, just make sure you tell me how :) I'm definitely not an expert.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this on a Pi. Try using Easy Install. My comments in []

Easy Install requires a working build environment. This is installed by default on many Linux distributions. [But not Pi] Otherwise, to install a build environment use the following commands (as root):

apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential curl g++ gettext shared-mime-info libssl-dev zlib1g-dev

Then run Easy Install the normal way:

curl http://easyinstall.citadel.org/install | bash

[from http://www.citadel.org/doku.php?id=installation:easyinstall:easyinstall]

This compiles Citadel so will take some time. If this seems not to work just run again. this time is very fast, and will let you do the setup.

Comment: Well it worked.Althought i had a few dependencies missing that needed other dependencies and so on..So i used apt-get to install it and then easyinstall witch it didnt't gave me any errors this time.Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: It works! I couldn't get the citadel server working on y Pi3b following the instructions in the pimylifeup.com article (https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-email-server/) but rebuilding it per your suggestions fixed it. I didn't get any missing dependency problems.

Answer (score 0):

As a small update to this issue, you may find installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 on your Pi 2/3 a lot smoother. Ubuntu now offers their own proper [server images](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi-2-3) for RPi.

As of 18.04 the Pi wireless drivers are included, and Citadel installed effortlessly and fully (inc. login) functional.

I have 18.04/Citadel running with 140Mb/RAM and about 2% CPU whilst idle using the Pi 3B+.